# PWA on iOS 13.4.1: Text selection stopped to work

Tags: ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps, iphone-xr

I have PWA on my iPhone XR.
After a recent iOS update I've got text selection not working inside PWA on iPhone XR.
And the same working on iPhone XS Max.

Text selection seems to be blocked inside PWA :/
Any help on the case would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation:
apparently text selection is broken for PWAs with `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` on iPhone XR (at least).

Filed a bug to webkit
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212299

Minimal reproducible html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test text selection</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>

<body>
  Try to select this text.<br/>
  Should be selectable but it is not on my iPhone XR.
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apparently this bug will be fixed in one of the next releases of iOS.  
Unfortunately not in 13.5.1 (still reproducible)  
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210191

Comment: The issue is finally fixed on iOS 13.6